# Need to set the class of a parent div to that of a contained li element

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a side navigation element which needs to change color based on which menu is selected. I'm trying to set the class of a parent div to match that of a li which is part of the menu. Here's the code:

```
<div class="cols" id="leftMenuWrapper">
    <div id="leftmenu">
        <ul id="navsub_657930_721861">
            <li class="lmenu_item2"><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I need to set the class of "leftmenu" to "lmenu_item2". I tried this jQuery but it didn't work.

```
$('#leftmenu').addClass($('#leftmenu ul li').class());
```

I'm assuming the issue is with .class in the code above. Not sure how to grab the class from the li.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would [use `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of the attribute you want:

```
$('#leftmenu ul li').attr('className');
```

Or if this is part of a click handler on the `<li>` element, you can reference the one that was clicked with `this`.

```
$(this).attr('className');
```

Comment: What's the advantage to `className` versus just `class`?

Comment: @mway - None, except that it keeps me in the habit of not using the future reserved word `class`, which will break in some situations for some browsers (variable name, property name, etc.). It doesn't break anything as a string, so `"class"` would work just fine here as well.

Comment: Ah, touche.  I can agree with that.

Comment: @mvan - A good example is when creating an element, you can pass an object to set its attributes, like `$('<div>', {class:"myClass"} )`. This will break (in some browsers) if you don't use `className`, or put quotes around `"class"`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be :

```
$('#leftmenu ul li').attr('class');
```